# Rails form_for declaration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting an `undefined method 'players_path` when trying to bring up a form for a new player in a Ruby on Rails application. The problem is, I have my player route nested in a declaration like the following:

```
namespace :manage do
    get "/" => 'management#index'

    scope :nfl do
        resources :players
    end
  end
```

That means a new player resource in this context would have a path of `new_manage_player`, but my form declaration has the following:

```
<%= form_for @player, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

Is there a way to modify this form declaration so that the app doesn't break with players_path is not defined? I don't have players_path explicitly defined anywhere else, so I'm assuming form_for @player is what's causing it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention your namespace and scope in the decleration.

```
<%= form_for [:manage, @player], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

Comment: [:manage, @player] did it, I guess it doesn't care about scope nesting. Thanks so much Douglas!

Comment: Edited answer for future clarity. Yep, I guess since the scope just adds properties to a set of routes, the URL helpers don't need to know about it.